# How to filter similar string in php?

Tags: php

This is my example:

```
$string1 = "I love php coding and want to get some help";
$string2 = "I like java coding and like to help other people" ;
$output = anyfunction($string1, $string2);
```

And I want to get output = **I coding and to help**

Is there any built-in function in php to do this task?

Comment: What is your question? Please update it and details what do you want from that function. What do you mean by "similar string"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare All strings in a array to all strings in another array, PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946724/compare-all-strings-in-a-array-to-all-strings-in-another-array-php)

Comment: I believe what you need is `Longest Common Subsequence`. I found this by googling: https://github.com/eloquent/php-lcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<?php
$string1 = "I love php coding and want to get some help";
$string2 = "I like java coding and like to help other people" ;
  function getCommonCharacter($str1,$str2,$case_sensitive = false)
  {
    $ary1 = explode(' ',$str1);
    $ary2 = explode(' ',$str2);

    if ($case_sensitive)
    {
      $ary1 = array_map('strtolower',$ary1);
      $ary2 = array_map('strtolower',$ary2);
    }

    echo (implode(' ',array_intersect($ary1,$ary2)));
  }
  getCommonCharacter($string1,$string2,$case_sensitive = false);
  ?>
```

Output:-http://prntscr.com/746ewy

Note:- case sensitivity taken false to match lower or uppercase as well. And you can change to see other results.Thanks.

Comment: 4 minutes have to wait.